# Setting correct size for "cryptsetup: WARNING: Option 'size' missing in crypttab for plain dm-crypt mapping root" message

Tags: encryption, 18.10, ecryptfs, cryptsetup

I have a full disk encryption using `ecryptfs`, after upgrading to *18.10* a warning message started to appearing at boot:

> cryptsetup: WARNING: Option 'size' missing in crypttab for plain
>   dm-crypt mapping root. Please read /usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.initramfs and add the correct 'size'
>   option to your crypttab(5).

From what I see at `/usr/share/doc/cryptsetup-initramfs/README.initramfs.gz` I should edit `/etc/cryptsetup` and set the  correct *size*, but how should this **size** be calculated for my system?

This is the content of `/etc/crypttab`:

```
 cryptswap1 UUID=1d1XXXXXXXXXXXX /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the size like `size=256` to `/etc/crypttab` configuration:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=1d1XXXXXXXXXXXX /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256
```

Comment: You ask how this size should be calculated and then post an answer that does not explain how to calculate this at all and mark it as the correct answer? So far no one has answered in this thread how to calculate this size. Please add this to your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Editing the 'crypttab' file was not enough in my case (upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04).

**After editing the file**, I had to disable (temporary) the swap file and re-generate the initramfs image:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
sudo swapon -a
```

Unfortunately, that step should be repeated after every kernel update.

Comment: If this has to be done after every kernel update, shouldn't it be considered as a bug?

Comment: I think it is a bug.

Comment: I was about to report a bug but I then switched to a question (see https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/693615). Let's see what happens now.

Comment: There is now a bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1903920).

Answer (score 5):

(In order to come up with a complete answer to this question, I'm posting this one, as an extension to [marcanuy's own answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109465/1653337).)

Note: The warning considered (above) stems from the [Debian Cryptsetup Initramfs integration](https://cryptsetup-team.pages.debian.net/cryptsetup/README.initramfs.html).

1. Find the size of the encryption key in question. Therefor, let's ask cryptsetup itself (for me, the problem has shown up regarding the encrypted swap partition on /dev/sda5):

   ```
   $ sudo cryptsetup status cryptswap1  
   /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is active and is in use.  
   type: PLAIN  
   cipher: aes-xts-plain64  
   keysize: 256 bits
   key location: dm-crypt
   device: /dev/sda5  
   [...]
   ```
2. Read `keysize` (and `type`).
3. If `type: PLAIN`, add the **size** (taken from above) to the corresponding entry in /etc/crypttab (as sudo):

   ```
   cryptroot /dev/sda5 none cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256,hash=sha1
   ```

   For a swap partition, the entry might look slightly different (eg., using `/dev/urandom` as (random) key file)
4. Re-generate initramfs (does **not** have to be re-done by you on kernel update):

   ```
   $ sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

   This might throw a warning, which can be ignored to my best knowledge. The warning regarding missing `size` option missing while booting, however, should have disappeared.
5. Finally, reboot to verify everything works as expected and the warning has gone.

Remark: For `type: LUKS`, /etc/crypttab should actually rather look as follows, as most of the information can be read from the mandatory LUKS header:

```
cryptroot /dev/sdaX none luks,discard
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have encrypted swap partitions, the correct way to prevent initramfs from using them for resume is to add:

`RESUME=none`
into
`/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

For example:

```
echo "RESUME=none" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```