# Warning message at boot: Option 'size' missing in crypttab (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, encryption

I am dual booting Ubuntu 20.04 installed with a dedicated home and swap partition. I encrypted both home and swap using encryptfs after install. Since then no issues or whatsoever. After running some updates today I got a warning message at boot stating that:

> cryptsetup: WARNING: Option 'size' missing in crypttab for plain
>   dm-crypt mapping cryptswap1. Please read
>   /usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.initramfs and add the correct 'size'
>   option to your crypttab(5).

Following the suggestion in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109463/setting-correct-size-for-cryptsetup-warning-option-size-missing-in-crypttab) thread I added the option `size=256` to the content of /etc/crypttab:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256
```

Didn't work though, the warning message at boot still persists with no noticable effect to the system.

The output of sudo cryptsetup status /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is as following:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is active and is in use.
  type:    PLAIN
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 256 bits
  key location: dm-crypt
  device:  /dev/sda4
  sector size:  512
  offset:  1024 sectors
  size:    39060480 sectors
  mode:    read/write
```

I will appreciate some advice here, thanks.